# Mentioning another negative action

Tags: construction

> **I can speak English as well as Chris can. CLEAR.**

What if we both can't?

> **I can't speak English as well as Chris can't. (wrong)**
>
> **I can't speak English and neither can Chris. (maybe correct)**

But I want to say that the way we don't speak English is the same. So, I think my third sentence doesn't convey it accurately. What do you suggest instead?

Answer (score 2):

You need the negative of "well", rather than the negative of "can".  That is you should use "badly":

> I speak English as badly as Chris.

If "can't" is absolutely required, "I can't speak English, and Chris is as bad as me."

Comment: 'I can't speak English any better than Chris [can]' and 'I speak English no better than Chris'  work if the listener knows somehow that Chris can't speak it well. 'I can't speak German any better than my dog, (or that wooden post over there)' always works.

Comment: "I am not able to explain this stuff just as every one else here can't either" - possible?